# How to make a command run on startup on KDE Manjaro

Tags: shell-script, manjaro

I have created this edited xkbmap file and I guess making it default with the command in the screenshot. I was able to make the file executable by adding `#!/bin/sh` at the beginning and running `chmod +x capsfix` but I couldn't figure out how to run it at startup.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuo could use `cron` with the non-standard option `@reboot` :

```
crontab -e
# Select the editor if not yet done
# add an entry like this to the end of the file
@reboot    /path/to/your/script
```

Or, since it seem a simple command, instead of a script you could add it to your `shell` personal configuration file.
If you use `bash` for example, you could add the command to the end of the `.bashrc` in yor home directory.

Comment: .bashrc solution worked perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great. A pleasure to help. But if the answer help you, you should accept it.